# How to include non-linear functions to TinyGP?

Tags: java, recursion, genetic-programming

I am trying to extend the function set of the TinyGP software to include non linear functions, such as sin, cos and tan. 
The problem is, the printing of the tree is done with recursion, printing an individual, then the function (+, -, *, /) and then another individual. So the result is something like (X2 * 2.365789). But, sin takes only one parameter, sin(x). How could the printing method be updated?

The source code of the printing method is outlined below.

```
int print_indiv( char []buffer, int buffercounter ) {
int a1=0, a2;
if ( buffer[buffercounter] < FSET_START ) {
  if ( buffer[buffercounter] < varnumber )
    System.out.print( "X"+ (buffer[buffercounter] + 1 )+ " ");
  else
    System.out.print( x[buffer[buffercounter]]);
  return( ++buffercounter );
  }
switch(buffer[buffercounter]) {
  case ADD: System.out.print( "(");
    a1=print_indiv( buffer, ++buffercounter ); 
    System.out.print( " + "); 
    break;
  case SUB: System.out.print( "(");
    a1=print_indiv( buffer, ++buffercounter ); 
    System.out.print( " - "); 
    break;
  case MUL: System.out.print( "(");
    a1=print_indiv( buffer, ++buffercounter ); 
    System.out.print( " * "); 
    break;
  case DIV: System.out.print( "(");
    a1=print_indiv( buffer, ++buffercounter ); 
    System.out.print( " / "); 
    break;
  }
a2=print_indiv( buffer, a1 ); 
System.out.print( ")"); 
return( a2);}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but something along this line should work:

```
/* ... */
switch(buffer[buffercounter]) {
  /* .... */
  case SIN: System.out.print( "sin(");
    a1= ++buffercounter;
    break;
  /* ... */
  }

a2=print_indiv( buffer, a1 ); 
System.out.print( ")"); 
return( a2);
```